# Vaadin Grid : How to disable mouse event handler which runs inline editor?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm using Grid with switched-on editor (setEditorEnabled(true)), but I going to launch inline editor programmatically, by calling **editItem()** method. How to disable mouse event handler which runs inline editor?

Comment: Did you try `setEditorEnabled(false);` by default, in your button click listener (or whatever you have `to launch inline editor programmatically`) call `setEditorEnabled(true); editItem(itemId);` &  `setEditorEnabled(false);` again after closing the editor?

Comment: Thank you @Morfic! It works! I added **setEditorEnabled(true)** in my event listener and **setEditorEnabled(false)** in overridden **doCancelEditor()** Grid method.

Comment: Great, then you can post your solution in an answer and select it as the correct one, so anyone else who may have the same issue can find it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Morfic, I solved the problem as follows:

```
Grid grid = new Grid(){
    @Override
    protected void doCancelEditor() {
        super.doCancelEditor();
        setEditorEnabled(false); // disable the editor every time when editing is completed
    }
};

grid.setEditorEnabled(false); // by default the editor is disabled

....
// grid initialization
....

// create any component (button for example) which will call the editor
Button button = new Button("Edit");
button.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) event -> {
    grid.setEditorEnabled(true); // activate the editor when the desired event occurred
    grid.editItem(itemId); // call the editor with itemId (it may be selected itemId)
});
```